# linq left join with filtering in joined

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I am getting duplication meals here

```
IEnumerable<DTOHotMealsPrice> lst = (from m in this.dbEntity.HOT_MEALS
    join ml in this.dbEntity.HOT_MEALS_PRICE   on m.MEALSID equals ml.MEALSID into mls
    from mls1 in mls.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where mls1.HOTID==hotelId
    select new DTOHotMealsPrice
    {
        MEALSID = m.MEALSID,
        MEALSNAME = m.MEALSNAME,
        CHPRICE = mls1.CHPRICE,
        PRICE = mls1.PRICE,
        HOTID = mls1.HOTID
    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

I want to list all HOT_MEALS and also join with 
HOT_MEALS_PRICE when a mealsid reference on it

When `mls1.HOTID==hotelId`, this will getting innerjoin results
How could it will a proper result

Comment: Please provide your tables structures.

Comment: ` public partial class HOT_MEALS
    {
        public short MEALSID { get; set; }
        public string MEALSNAME { get; set; }
    }`` public partial class HOT_MEALS_PRICE
    {
        public short MEALSID { get; set; }
        public int HOTID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> PRICE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> CHPRICE { get; set; }
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Way solve Solution

Remove Where Case

Add where Case In  Join table

Show for Where Case Blow Linq Query

first Query

```
IEnumerable<DTOHotMealsPrice> lst = (from m in this.dbEntity.HOT_MEALS
join ml in this.dbEntity.HOT_MEALS_PRICE.where(c=>c.HOTID==hotelId)   on m.MEALSID equals ml.MEALSID into mls
from mls1 in mls.DefaultIfEmpty()   
select new DTOHotMealsPrice
{
    MEALSID = m.MEALSID,
    MEALSNAME = m.MEALSNAME,
    CHPRICE = mls1.CHPRICE,
    PRICE = mls1.PRICE,
    HOTID = mls1.HOTID
}).Distinct().ToList();
```

Second is:

```
IEnumerable<DTOHotMealsPrice> lst = (from m in this.dbEntity.HOT_MEALS
join ml in this.dbEntity.HOT_MEALS_PRICE   on m.MEALSID equals ml.MEALSID into mls
from mls1 in mls.where(c=>c.HOTID==hotelId).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new DTOHotMealsPrice
{
    MEALSID = m.MEALSID,
    MEALSNAME = m.MEALSNAME,
    CHPRICE = mls1.CHPRICE,
    PRICE = mls1.PRICE,
    HOTID = mls1.HOTID
}).Distinct().ToList();
```